# How to plot the name of a line segment in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to add the name to the line segment plotted in the figure. For example, I plot the segment containing two endpoints (0, 0) and (3, 3), and its name is segment1. How to draw its name “segment1" at the position (0, 1)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a [text](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) annotation using this syntax:

```
  figure

plot([0 3], [0 3]);
hText = text(1 ,0.7,'Segment 1','FontSize',16) % Using (1,1) as a position was not looking good :)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for a way to add text to a graph.

[This example](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/creating_plots/adding-text-to-graphs.html) should be a good place to start, it shows you how to use the `text` command or the `legend`:

[image]

```
% Define initial conditions
t0 = 0;
tfinal = 15;
y0 = [20 20]';
% Simulate the differential equation
tfinal = tfinal*(1+eps);
[t,y] = ode23('lotka',[t0 tfinal],y0);
% Plot the two curves, storing handles to them
% so their DisplayNames can be set
hlines = plot(t,y);
% Compose and display two multiline text
% annotations as cell arrays
str1(1) = {'Many Predators;'};
str1(2) = {'Prey Population'};
str1(3) = {'Will Decline'};
text(7,220,str1)
str2(1) = {'Few Predators;'};
str2(2) = {'Prey Population'};
str2(3) = {'Will Increase'};
text(5.5,125,str2)
% Set DisplayNames for the lines for use by the legend
set(hlines(1),'Displayname','Prey')
set(hlines(2),'Displayname','Predator')
% Center a legend at the top of the graph
legend('Location','north')
% Add a title with bold style
title('Lotka-Volterra Predator-Prey Population Model',... 
  'FontWeight','bold')
```

Note that the link also describes more advanced features.